# Why do I get HTTP 501 errors for certain requests?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, http-headers

I've written a simple webapp for myself to be able to edit files on my server, when I'm at a place that allows only http and https ports...

But I encountered a weird problem with it.

Normally these headers are exchanged when I save a file (confidential info removed):

```
https://example.com/?

POST /? HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: hu-HU,en-US;q=0.8,hu;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: https://example.com/?path=/home/csirmazd/public_html/[...]/fs/view/login.php&view=preview
Cookie: [...]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 644
[...]

HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2015 14:57:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.36
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: ?path=/home/csirmazd/public_html/[...]/fs/view/login.php&view=preview
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
----------------------------------------------------------
https://example.com/?path=/home/csirmazd/public_html/[...]/fs/view/login.php&view=preview

GET /?path=/home/csirmazd/public_html/[...]/fs/view/login.php&view=preview HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: hu-HU,en-US;q=0.8,hu;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: https://example.com/?path=/home/csirmazd/public_html/[...]/fs/view/login.php&view=preview
Cookie: [...]
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2015 14:57:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.36
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
----------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I try to save another specific file, namely dir.php something is different:

```
https://example.com/?

POST /? HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: hu-HU,en-US;q=0.8,hu;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: https://example.com/?path=/home/csirmazd/public_html/[...]/fs/view/dir.php&view=preview
Cookie: [...]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 4604
[...]

HTTP/1.1 501 Method Not Implemented
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2015 15:03:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
Allow: TRACE
Content-Length: 458
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Pad: avoid browser bug
----------------------------------------------------------
```

And the message in the browser is

```
GET to / not supported.
```

What? Then why does it work for everything else?

The underlying PHP code isn't invoked at all.

First I thought it's a buggy .htaccess. But if I remember I disabled it, by having single `RewriteEngine On` in it in the root directory. So I don't think that's the issue. (It still processes *example.com/* by invoking the *index.php* for it.)

My second thought was that the maximum size of POST requests is very small. But I can edit larger files without problems.

Now I ran out of ideas I don't know where to look.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the root of the problem is the ModSecurity module on Apache server installed by the hosting provider.

As [others had issues with it too on a different site](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/biult-in-editor-http-501-505-when-saving-files).

So I tried an experiment and posted the same content to a random URI and got the same error as before. Obviously this thing doesn't like when you submit code from forms.

So the obvious solution is turning it off.

In my particular case there is no option in my cPanel to turn it off, so I managed to bypass it by base64 encoding the form content on client side.